# How to collapse a box in Adminlte from the title

Tags: user-experience, adminlte

I want to collapse the default box without having to find a tiny plus and minus button.

The title area is a good location to start as this whole area is visible when collapsed, so even if the user misses the control button there chances have increased.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can actually move the data-widget to the header, and include the icon inside

```
<div class="box-header with-border" data-widget="collapse">
 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
 ...
```

That way you can control the open close from a larger surface, good for mobile etc..
[image]